# Is it possible to loop through the id attribute of an img tag with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, object

I have developed the following block of code using HTML and Javascript that's completely functional:

```
<html>
   <body>
      <img id="img0" style="position:fixed; width:116px; height:100px;" >
      <img id="img1" style="position:fixed; width:116px; height:100px;" >
      <img id="img2" style="position:fixed; width:116px; height:100px;" >
      <img id="img3" style="position:fixed; width:116px; height:100px;" >

      <script>
         let rightArray = [300, 213, 387, 300 ];
         let bottomArray = [300, 350, 350, 200];
         let imageArray = ['image1.png', 'image2.png', 'image3.png', 'image4.png'];

         const img0 = document.querySelector('#img0');
         img0.style.right = rightArray[0] + "px";
         img0.style.bottom = bottomArray[0] + "px";
         img0.src = imageArray[0];

         const img1 = document.querySelector('#img1');
         img1.style.right = rightArray[1] + "px";
         img1.style.bottom = bottomArray[1] + "px";
         img1.src = imageArray[1];

         const img2 = document.querySelector('#img2');
         img2.style.right = rightArray[2] + "px";
         img2.style.bottom = bottomArray[2] + "px";
         img2.src = imageArray[2];

         const img3 = document.querySelector('#img3');
         img3.style.right = rightArray[3] + "px";
         img3.style.bottom = bottomArray[3] + "px";
         img3.src = imageArray[3];

      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Basically it organizes some hexagonal images in the following pattern:
[image]

As we can see on the code everything is very repetitive and it would be more convenient to make this code inside a loop. But I'd need a way to put the `img tag` inside the loop for doing that. The pseudo-code of what I want to do is something like this:

```
<html>
   <body>
      for(let i=0; i<4; i++)
      {
      <img id="img[i]" style="position:fixed; width:116px; height:100px;" >
      }

      <script>
         let rightArray = [300, 213, 387, 300 ];
         let bottomArray = [300, 350, 350, 200];
         let imageArray = ['image1.png', 'image2.png', 'image3.png', 'image4.png'];
         let objectNameArray = ['img0', 'img1', 'img2', 'img3'];

      for(let i=0; i<4; i++)
      {
         const objectNameArray[i] = document.querySelector('#' + objectNameArray[i]);
         objectNameArray[i].style.right = rightArray[i] + "px";
         objectNameArray[i].style.bottom = bottomArray[i] + "px";
         objectNameArray[i].src = imageArray[i];
      }
      </script>

   </body>
</html>
```

I'm 100% sure that this last code is not functional, the first loop is completely wrong and the second one we can't declare and use objects in the way that I did there. So, basically **I have two doubts here:**

1. **Is it possible to put the img tag inside a loop so I don't need to copy it a lot of times when I'm handling its parameters with Javascript?**
2. **Is it possible to declare and use different objects that were created with the loop interactions?**

---

These questions appeared in my mind just because I wanted to optimize the first block of code that I posted here... I'm not sure if what I want to do is possible or if I'm trying to do it in the right way. So I'm open for different perspectives of doing the same thing in different ways.
Thanks!!

Comment: You can loop over `document.querySelector("img")` directly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using `id`s, you could put the necessary data in an array, and loop through the array:

```js
const data = [
  { right: 100, bottom: 100, url: 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/SjeyK.jpg?s=32&g=1'},
  { right: 20, bottom: 20, url: 'image2.png'},
  { right: 387, bottom: 350, url: 'image3.png'},
  { right: 300, bottom: 200, url: 'image4.png'},
];
data.forEach(({ right, bottom, url }) => {
  const img = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('img'));
  img.src = url;
  img.style.right = right + 'px';
  img.style.bottom = bottom + 'px';
});
```

```css
img {
  position:fixed; width:116px; height:100px;
}
```

It would be even better to set these attributes in CSS only, though, if that's an option for you.

Comment: Thanks... That was exactly what I needed. But why do you say that it would be better to set the attributes using CSS only? Is there a specific reason or it's more about good practices when I'm creating a web page?

Comment: It allows for greater separation of concerns. It's better if, for example, when you need to make a change, you only have to open the appropriate CSS file and change style as needed, instead of having to go into the programmable logic and change the script code itself.

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```js
/* I changed the bottomArray values so that the images are visible in the following code snippet */
var rightArray = [300, 213, 387, 300 ],
    bottomArray = [100, 150, 150, 0],
    imageArray = [ 'gbwzdT/image1.png', 'mrWAk8/image2.png', 'f6qQJT/image3.png', 'cunGQ8/image4.png' ];

for ( var i = 0; i < 4; i++ ) {
    var element = document.createElement( 'img' );

    element.id = 'img' + i;
    element.style.cssText = 'position:fixed; width:116px; height:100px; right: ' + rightArray[ i ] + 'px; bottom: ' + bottomArray[ i ] + 'px';
    element.src = 'https://image.ibb.co/' + imageArray[ i ];
    document.body.appendChild( element )
}
```